# Google chrome for android clear or disable cache

Tags: google-chrome, jsf

I'm using google chrome for android on kiosk mode to use my web application. I need to clear or disable his cache without using "More tools and then Clear browsing data". It must be automatic when the server side change.
Is it possible ?

My web application is develop with JSF
Versions :
Chrome 64.0.3282.137
Android 7.0.0

Thanks